# how to resize Checkbox on android?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

i'm using Jquery mobile and html to make a login page with a remember me check box

```
 <td align="right" style="width: 30%; padding-right:4%;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Remember"  name="Remember" data-role="none"                                   
     style="background-color: White; font-size: 100%; height: 33px; width: 34px;"/>
  </td>
```

the issue is that this check box doesn't want to resized on Samsung note2 "OS Android 4.1"
any help how can i resize this check box

Comment: I can't test this in Android, but [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tcpLV/) may be helpful. MDN on [`transform` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform#scale). I made it using chrome (webkit) and there seems to be a bug if _scale_ is used by itself on a checkbox, so I showed a couple ways to get it working (in chrome).

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't what you asked for but as an alternative solution:

Create your own checkbox using two images (checked and unchecked) and some JavaScript. It'll be guaranteed to consistently look and work on all mobile devices then.